# How to detect scrolling in div when position is fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am trying to detect scrolling in a div which is inside a div with `position:fixed;`.
This div with position fixed property is being added to DOM by javascript so i am attaching event handler like this

```
$(document).on('scroll', '.scroll_div', function(){ 
    console.log("scrolled!"); 
});
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Could you please add your HTML and CSS to the question. A working example in http://jsfiddle.net wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: i made a jsfiddle for it. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/vtuuwL3a/) , please check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use, everytime AFTER, when You add new `.scroll_div` element to DOM.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9g6g2rwd/1/)

```
$('.scroll_div').off('scroll').on('scroll', function(){ 

     console.log("scrolled!"); 
});
```

Comment: It works perfectly but can you please tell me what you did here.

Comment: Disable all binded `scroll` events from last bind and bind new event. $(document).on('event', 'element') is not same than $('element').on('event'), because first example working for element which will be added in future, but in this case, `scroll` event is not supported for $(document).on binding. So everytime when You add new `.scroll_div` element to DOM, You will use this code.

Comment: No problem. If You have any other questions, tell me. Have a good day Vinit : )